# Select a rectangular block of text in Word 2013

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, selection

I'm pretty sure that older versions of Microsoft Word would let me select a rectangular block of text by holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while dragging the mouse from one corner to the other. When I try it with Word 2013, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> just shows me a bunch of keyboard short cut hints. It may be related to the fact that I'm running Windows 7 under VirtualBox on Ubuntu.

How can I select a rectangular block of text in Word 2013?

Comment: Works fine in Word 2013 using ALT for me.  Just because it (also) shows the keyboard shortcuts in the ribbon doesn't seem to prevent it from being used as you suggest.

Comment: If it works for you, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, it may be a problem with running under VirtualBox. I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite as nice as using the mouse, but there is a [keyboard short cut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290938) for selecting a vertical block of text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.